# Configure vim-projectionist in Neovim with Lua

Tags: lua, neovim

I'm using [vim-projectionist](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist) with Neovim and have been able to get it working with a simple `.projections.json` file at the root of our project:

```json
{
  "src/components/*.tsx": {
    "type": "components"
  }
}
```

Although this works, I can't check-in this file in our shared GitHub repository.

Rather than use the config file, the [documentation](https://github.com/tpope/vim-projectionist#example) suggests that you can set a global variable `g:projectionist_heuristics` for configuration instead.

As my Neovim config is entirely in Lua, I'm trying to get this working in my `init.lua` file.

Here is my attempt:

```lua
vim.cmd([[
let g:projectionist_heuristics = {
  \   "src/components/*.tsx": {
  \     "type": "components"
  \   }
  \ }
]])
```

When I open Neovim nothing happens...it seems that my `vim.cmd` snippet is ignored.

Or, perhaps I should be using Lua tables?

**How can I configure `vim-projectionist` in Neovim with Lua?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I managed to configure it in AstroNvim (https://astronvim.com/)

```
  {
    "tpope/vim-projectionist",
    config = function()
      vim.g.projectionist_heuristics = {
        ["*"] = {
          ["src/main/java/*.java"] = {
            alternate = "src/test/java/{}Test.java",
          },
          ["src/test/java/*Test.java"] = {
            alternate = "src/main/java/{}.java",
          },
        },
      }
    end,
    event = "User AstroFile",
  },
```

The configuration above uses the Lazy package manager syntax:
https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim